# Change Data Capture and Dynamics AX

Tags: sql-server, ssis, axapta, etl, cdc

In order to optimize the integration of data from the Axapta system, we will want to ask them to enable Change Data Capture (CDC) for tracking the changes tables and improve our ETL with SSIS 2012 (incremental load etc).

But I do not know anything about the Axapata system. Does activation of CDC on their operational base Axapta might cause them trouble? Should take special precautions ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are documented scenarios where CDC is recommended, see [Configuring AIF for change tracking](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh433529.aspx).

In rare cases [AX synchronization](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa548671.aspx) may decide to rename a table, create a new table, copy records from the old to the new and finally drop the old table. In this case I would expect that the CDC settings for the table would be dropped too.

I don't think CDC is widely used though, so don't expect a lot of answers.
[This link](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/p/34212/59992.aspx) may be useful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I didn't find anything on websites :( Maybe I need make a concept of proof...

Comment: I don't think CDC would have any serious impact on AX unless used on high volume transaction tables.

Comment: But it will be a problem if AX may decide to rename, drop tables etc. The CDC will not work correctly

Comment: Sure, but it should be a low frequency problem, especially if your table schema is stable. You will probably need a SQL script or an AX class with direct SQL to enable CDC anyway. Then run that after each deployment to live.